# jQuery show then hide with code in beween, show not rendering

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I developed a spinner using the suggestions on:

http://blog.oio.de/2010/11/08/how-to-create-a-loading-animation-spinner-using-jquery/

The spinner works when I do nothing but let it run without trying to hide it.

But I am embedding the spinner as the bookends of the code in a function.  I show it at the start, and end it at the end.  But it never shows, even when I load enough data so that the delay is over one second.

Here is the code:

```
    function SortListByDistance(SortReferenceLatitude, SortReferenceLongitude)
    {
        $("#SpinnerControl").show();

        $(".RetailerSearchSectionLine").each(function()
        {
            var SortLocationLatitude = $(".RetailLocationLatitude", $(this)).text();
            var SortLocationLongitude = $(".RetailLocationLongitude", $(this)).text();
            var DistanceFromReferenceLocation = CalculateDistance(SortReferenceLatitude, SortReferenceLongitude, SortLocationLatitude, SortLocationLongitude);
            $(this).data("DistanceFromReferenceLocation", DistanceFromReferenceLocation);
        });

        var TransferArray = $("#RetailerSearchSectionBody ul li").toArray().sort(function(a, b)
        {
            var distance1 = $(a).data("DistanceFromReferenceLocation");
            var distance2 = $(b).data("DistanceFromReferenceLocation");
            return (distance1 - distance2);
        });

        $("#RetailerSearchSectionBody ul").append(TransferArray);
        $("#RetailerSearchSectionBody").scrollTop(0);

        $("#SpinnerControl").hide();
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why the show doesn't render?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some browsers you need to relinquish control back to the browser in order for UI to update. Usually not a problem in Firefox, but it is in Chrome/IE...

I would recommend using a timeout to let the browser do its work as well (keep in mind that this makes `SortListByDistance` asynchronous):

```
function SortListByDistance(SortReferenceLatitude, SortReferenceLongitude)
{
    $("#SpinnerControl").show();

    setTimeout( function( ) {
        $(".RetailerSearchSectionLine").each(function()
        {
            var SortLocationLatitude = $(".RetailLocationLatitude", $(this)).text();
            var SortLocationLongitude = $(".RetailLocationLongitude", $(this)).text();
            var DistanceFromReferenceLocation = CalculateDistance(SortReferenceLatitude, SortReferenceLongitude, SortLocationLatitude, SortLocationLongitude);
            $(this).data("DistanceFromReferenceLocation", DistanceFromReferenceLocation);
        });

        var TransferArray = $("#RetailerSearchSectionBody ul li").toArray().sort(function(a, b)
        {
            var distance1 = $(a).data("DistanceFromReferenceLocation");
            var distance2 = $(b).data("DistanceFromReferenceLocation");
            return (distance1 - distance2);
        });

        $("#RetailerSearchSectionBody ul").append(TransferArray);
        $("#RetailerSearchSectionBody").scrollTop(0);

        $("#SpinnerControl").hide();
    }, 1 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ryan.  Same suggestion as the one immediately following (thank you, James).  Both work, with this added information:  The spinner stops spinning after the ms parm transpires (I increased it to 100ms).  But it shows.  So, precisely because JS is not async, as soon as the sort routine starts, the spinner stops spinning but stays on screen.  So I think I will use a static image/text combo to get what I want done.  The spinner was designed for ajax calls.  This is not ajax, hence the single thread behavior exhibited.  Thank you for showing me the way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that no visible changes are made to the screen until the code finishes executing.  Once it finishes, the element is already hidden so you never see it.  If your intent is to show the element while the code executes, use `setTimeout`:

```
$("#SpinnerControl").show();

setTimeout(function(){
    // do you stuff here

    $("#SpinnerControl").hide();
}, 1);
```

Comment: The problem with a set timeout is that there is not guarantee the code has executed.

Comment: Same answer as above.  See comment.  Thank you, James.

Comment: @laymanje:  I do believe the show code will have executed before the thread passes to the setTimeout function, because JS is not aysnch.  The issue is when does the browser get to catch up with itself.  Other Q&A's have shown that setTimeout gives the browser a breather it can use to render stuff that otherwise waits until a block of code is executed.